# Show that if $M $ is orthogonal matrix, then $\det M =\pm 1$.

Tags: matrices, determinant, orthogonal-matrices

I write like following my prove, and I need to know if it's correct:

If P is an orthogonal matrix, then $$PP^t = I = P^tP$$ Therefore, $$\det(P^tP) = \det (I) \implies \det(P) \det (P^t) \implies \det (P) \det (P) = [\det (P)]^2$$   So $$ [\det(P)]^2 = 1 \implies \det (P) = \pm \sqrt 1 $$  So  $$ \det (P) = \pm 1$$

I prove it writing this, I would like to know if this proof is correct.

Comment: I think you have the right idea in there but it's put together a little clumsily. Here's a cleaner argument. We know that in general $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$. In our case $P^T P = I$, and so $\det(P^T P) = \det(I) = 1$. We also know that determinants are multiplicative, so $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$, giving $\det(P^T P) = \det(P^T) \det(P) = \det(P)^2$ which you have. Then $1 = \det(P)^2$ which means that $\det(P) = \pm 1$.

Comment: Also the statement $\Longrightarrow \det(P)\det(P^t)$ says nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $M$ is orthogonal, we have $$MM^T = I$$ It gives $$\det(MM^T) = \det(I) = 1$$ Therefore, $$\det(M) \det(M^T) = 1$$ now since $\det(M^T) = \det(M)$, we get $$\det(M)^2 = 1 \implies \det(M) = \pm 1$$